# Google Scholar Profiles by Country

Tags: google-scholar

In scholar we can list our fields of interest. Whenever you click them, scholar shows the most cited researchers in that field like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8YrZ.jpg). Is there a way to sort google scholar profiles by country, in a given field?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I missed that! Should I delete my question?

Comment: @RichardCosta If you agree it answers the question, it's better to accept it as a duplicate. Nothing really wrong with having a question marked as duplicate (well, better to search first, of course, but I mean after it's already been posted), and if someone happens to find yours by search it will point them to where they can find the answer.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841